# Freezing first row while highlighting row and column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to do a table where I need to freeze the top row and highlight the row and column on hover.
I have the 2 working separately but when I combine them, it isn't working right.

```css
#table_grid {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#table_grid td,
th {
  color: #669;
  padding: 9px 8px 4px 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
}

#table_grid tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5);
}

#table_grid td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.2);
  content: '\00a0';
  height: 10000px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5000px;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<table id="table_grid">
  <tr class="red">
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I change

```
overflow: hidden
```

to

```
overflow: auto
```

in #table_grid, the highlight on hover and freezing the first row is working but the hightlight on hover is running off the screen.

If I change it back to

```
overflow: hidden
```

Hightlight on hover is working properly but the first row is not freezing.

Is there any way to fix this?